# vertical-align doesn't work properly on not capitalized text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertical align, with pixel perfection in mind, two texts.

One is completely capitalized, the other is not.

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/EjxJoz

```
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 31px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 31px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As you can see, the capitalized text is perfectly centered (20px above and 20px below).

The other one, has 26px above, and 19px below.

I think it always centers the text assuming the higher possible character as center... but I'd like to center the current text considering only the used characters.

Is there a way?

**NB:** Using CSS tables will not fix the problem.

Comment: Not without tweaking the margins and/or positions. Even then, you may still see differences across different browsers and/or operating systems. If you remove all the other styles and just give the spans a bg colour, you can see why this is: http://prntscr.com/6xka0j

Comment: `vertical-align` has NO effects on text nodes; It affects the vertical alignment of inline-level elements having (or not having) text nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each browser only sets one baseline for the font. It doesn't care if you're using capitals or not. So naturally not every letter can be exactly centered because they have different heights and maybe descenders.

Vertical alignment is more a "close to"-value. When you set *vertical-align: top;* not all the letters will align to the top and bump the top-border, just the baseline of the font does.

Comment: I think that sadly this is the answer :(

Comment: I'm sorry it is. I've been spending days on this too some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
<div><span>ACEOU</span></div>
<div><span>aceou</span></div>

div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 31px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 31px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem is still there.

Comment: @FezVrasta Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/psrqdw5r/1/) out. You should also remove `float`s and `line-height`s when you are using CSS tables for vertical alignment.

Comment: @FezVrasta So you should define the *alignment*. It is not possible to align characters themselves in CSS, but the element containing those characters.

Comment: @FezVrasta On my screens I can see both the fiddle working fine. Don't know why..

Comment: Also because you don't want to use css table, the solution by @ketan looks perfect on my screen.

Comment: I need pixel perfection, use some tool lice xScope to measure the spaces and you'll notice the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do trick: Give `line-height` to span not to div.

**HTML:**

```
<div><span>ACEOU</span></div>
<div><span>aceou</span></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 31px;
  //vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;

}
span {
  line-height: 31px;
}
```

Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXNOPb

Comment: @FezVrasta actually this solution seems perfect on my screen if you don't want to use css table

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is setting different a different `line-height` for each `span`. It's an incredibly fiddly solution and there's no guarantee it will give you the exact same result (to the pixel) across different browsers and/or operating systems.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  height:33px;
  width:25%;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  text-indent:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div:first-of-type span{
  line-height: 31px;
}
div:last-of-type span{
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>ACEOU</span></div>
<div><span>aceou</span></div>
```